# switch to randomly selected view in xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, random-access

utilising xcode using the random function i want to switch to from a view to a randomly selected new view...can some one give me some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new view (randomly selected) subview of the current view or some view across your application?

For subviews: you could use the tag property of every view, assign a value to it and use `viewWithTag:` to find a view based on the tag (= the randomly generated number from before).

For views across your app: Why would you want to do something like this? Doesn't sound exactly like good design to me.

Comment: im trying to achieve a particular approach that may seem to to the savvy programmer like inefficient coding but i guess im experimenting if i use awake from nib can i load a view from wnen the a case is randomly selected... thanks for your help much appreciated